# Show web-application as fullscreen app in Windows 8

Tags: windows, web, safari, microsoft-metro

I'm building a web-app and I would like to display it as a full-screen app in Windows 8. The result should be something else like in safari on an apple iPad:

Safari:
I've added these two meta-tags in my index.html:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Then I opened my web-app in the safari of my iPad and added the site to my homescreen. After this, I got an icon on my homescreen and when I open it, there is my web-app in full-screen, without the browser-containers around it.

Can I do something else with the same web-app on Windows 8? I thought, I could create a metro app, when I add the site to my apps in Internet Explorer. But I think, I also need some meta tags. I found many tutorials on the web, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you create a Windows Hosted Web App

http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/HWA.htm

Using the Microsoft App Studio, you can do it in minutes

http://appstudio.windows.com/projects/create